# Bigquery python SchemaField() with ARRAY of STRUCTS

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm trying to create a table at Bigquery through python client. The docs uses `bigquery.SchemaField('name', 'TYPE')` to define a field. Although it doesn't seem to work for **ARRAYS** or **STRUCTS**. This is the ARRAY of STRUCTS field I'm trying to create:

```
bigquery.SchemaField('owners', 'ARRAY<STRUCT<emailAddress STRING, displayName STRING>>', 'REPEATABLE'),
```

If I use the field definition above I get the following API error:

```
400 POST https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/import-sheet/datasets/sheetgo/tables: Invalid value for: ARRAY<STRUCT<emailAddress STRING, displayName STRING>> is not a valid value
```

### The whole code:

```
schema = [
            bigquery.SchemaField('user', 'STRING'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('id', 'STRING'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('service_origin', 'STRING'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('name', 'STRING'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('mimeType', 'STRING'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('createdAt', 'DATETIME'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('ownedByMe', 'BOOLEAN'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('owners', 'ARRAY<STRUCT<emailAddress STRING, displayName STRING>>', 'REPEATABLE'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('parents', 'ARRAY<STRING>', 'REPEATABLE'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('teamDriveId', 'STRING'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('permissions', 'STRING'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('shared', 'BOOLEAN'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('writersCanShare', 'BOOLEAN'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('sharingUser', 'STRING'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('version', 'STRING'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('size', 'FLOAT'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('data_properties', 'ARRAY<STRUCT<'
                                                        'rows INTEGER,'
                                                        'cells_with_importrange ARRAY<'
                                                                                    'STRUCT<'
                                                                                        'row_index INTEGER,'
                                                                                        'col_index INTEGER,'
                                                                                        'importrange STRING'
                                                                                      '>'
                                                                                    '>,'
                                                        'tab_name STRING,'
                                                        'cell_count FLOAT,'
                                                        'header_rows ARRAY<STRING>,'
                                                    '>>', 'REPEATABLE'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('timezone', 'STRING'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('locale', 'STRING'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('last_scansheet', 'STRING'),
        ]

        bigquery_client = bigquery.Client(PROJECT_ID)
        dataset_ref = bigquery_client.dataset("eita")

        table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)
        table = bigquery.Table(table_ref, schema=schema)

        table = bigquery_client.create_table(table)
```

### UPDATE

Thanks to [Willian Fuks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1002277/willian-fuks), I got this working. The end result for the schema ended up like this:

```
schema = [
            bigquery.SchemaField('user', 'STRING'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('id', 'STRING'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('service_origin', 'STRING'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('name', 'STRING'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('mimeType', 'STRING'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('createdAt', 'DATETIME'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('ownedByMe', 'BOOLEAN'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('owners', 'RECORD', mode='REPEATED',
                fields=(
                    bigquery.SchemaField('emailAddress', 'STRING'),
                    bigquery.SchemaField('displayName', 'STRING')
                )
            ),
            bigquery.SchemaField('parents', 'STRING', mode='REPEATED'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('teamDriveId', 'STRING'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('permissions', 'STRING'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('shared', 'BOOLEAN'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('writersCanShare', 'BOOLEAN'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('sharingUser', 'STRING'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('version', 'STRING'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('size', 'FLOAT'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('data_properties', 'RECORD', mode='REPEATED',
                 fields=(
                     bigquery.SchemaField('rows', 'INTEGER'),
                     bigquery.SchemaField('cells_with_importrange', 'RECORD', mode='REPEATED',
                          fields=(
                              bigquery.SchemaField('row_index', 'INTEGER'),
                              bigquery.SchemaField('col_index', 'INTEGER'),
                              bigquery.SchemaField('importrange', 'STRING'),
                          )
                      ),
                     bigquery.SchemaField('tab_name', 'STRING'),
                     bigquery.SchemaField('cell_count', 'FLOAT'),
                     bigquery.SchemaField('header_rows', 'STRING', mode='REPEATED')
                 )
             ),
            bigquery.SchemaField('timezone', 'STRING'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('locale', 'STRING'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('last_scansheet', 'STRING'),
        ]
```

Comment: It would be nice if you can include a complete code, not just the schema part. So other people can have a good reference. :)

Comment: Yeah I am more confused about dumping struct data using python @YanniCao.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The constructor's contract for `SchemaField` does [expect different inputs](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/master/bigquery/google/cloud/bigquery/schema.py#L18) from the ones you used.

Try this instead:

```
schema = [
    (...),
    SchemaField('owners', 'RECORD', mode='REPEATED',
        fields=(SchemaField('emailAddress', 'STRING'),
                SchemaField('displayName', 'STRING')
        )
    ),
    (...)
]
```

Main idea is to define fields inside of a record field by using other `SchemaField` definitions.

Comment: Perfect! I will update my question to include the solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use standard SQL type names instead of working with legacy SQL types and `SchemaField`, you can instead execute a query to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE dataset.table_name
(
  user STRING,
  id STRING,
  service_origin STRING,
  name STRING,
  mimeType STRING,
  createdAt DATETIME,
  ownedByMe BOOL,
  owners ARRAY<STRUCT<emailAddress STRING, displayName STRING>>,
  parents ARRAY<STRING>,
  teamDriveId STRING,
  permissions STRING,
  shared BOOL,
  writersCanShare BOOL,
  sharingUser STRING,
  version STRING,
  size FLOAT64,
  data_properties
    ARRAY<STRUCT<`rows` INT64,
                 cells_with_importrange ARRAY<STRUCT<row_index INT64, col_index INT64, importrange STRING>>,
                 tab_name STRING, cell_count FLOAT64, header_rows ARRAY<STRING>>>,
  timezone STRING,
  locale STRING,
  last_scansheet STRING
);
```

Comment: What command do you use to get this query to work? We found it worked in the web console - but couldn't get the standard python "client.query(sql)" command to get the sql statement to create a table.

Comment: You should probably create a separate question showing the code that you are using.