# How to dump a json with unknown contents in bigquery?

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery

I have would like to insert a json field into big query. A typical json is a request payload from all different API requests on our web page. Hence a typical json can have a different structure and size. As such I cannot decide upon a schema for the json to be inserted as a RECORD Field in Big Query. Examples of two such jsons are:

```
JSON1 = {
"key": "abcd",
"user_id": "1234FGH",
"start": 5,
"end": 10
}
```

```
JSON2 = {
"key": "efgh",
"creator_id": "789HIJ",
"content_id": "5678XYZ",
"from": 5,
"size": 10
}
```

As evident these jsons are different in structure. I have payloads from hundreds of APIs with each having hundreds of fields in their request json, hence I cannot afford to create a schema for the Record field in BigQuery.

Here is my python code:

```
import os

from google.cloud import bigquery

BIG_Q_CREDENTIALS = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_BIGQ_CREDENTIALS")
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = BIG_Q_CREDENTIALS

TABLE_ID = os.environ.get("BIGQ_TABLE_ID")
DATASET_ID = os.environ.get("BIGQ_DATASET_ID")

bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
dataset_ref = bigquery_client.dataset(DATASET_ID)
table_ref = dataset_ref.table(TABLE_ID)

try:
    table = bigquery_client.get_table(table_ref)
except Exception as e:
    schema = [
                bigquery.SchemaField("event_name", "STRING", mode="REQUIRED"),
                bigquery.SchemaField("uuid", "STRING", mode="REQUIRED"),
                bigquery.SchemaField("request_payload", "RECORD", mode="NULLABLE"),
                bigquery.SchemaField("createdtime", "TIMESTAMP", mode="REQUIRED"),
            ]
    table = bigquery.Table(table_ref, schema=schema)
    table = bigquery_client.create_table(table)
```

The code errors out with:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/{PROJECT_ID}/datasets/{DATASET_NAME}/tables: Field request_payload is type RECORD but has no schema
```

Should I dump this payload as string? But my concern is that querying on it would be economically expensive.

Any help would be appreciated. Please let me know if you need anything from my end to help me solve this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bigquery python SchemaField() with ARRAY of STRUCTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49542974/bigquery-python-schemafield-with-array-of-structs)

Answer (score 1):

> As such I cannot decide upon a schema for the JSON to be inserted as a
>   RECORD Field in Big Query.

That is understandable. The common use case for a JSON is it to be flexible.

[RECORD is like a Struct](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#standard_sql_data_types), so you need to specify the fields beforehand, each with a type (required) and field name (optional). That is why you should use STRING instead: `bigquery.SchemaField("request_payload", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE")` , and whenever you like to read from your payload, you can use [JSON_EXTRACT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions) and get the field you like.

For instance, you will get the user_id by running the following query:

```
SELECT *, JSON_EXTRACT(request_payload, "$.user_id") FROM `Project.Dataset.Table`
```